# Dualhead X1800XT cold plug not working, but hot plug is working

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, ati, dualhead

When I have two monitors attached to my x1800xt during bootup, X, Unity or the graphics driver crashes during the last stage (loading UI when the monitor setup changes from mirror to extended, tty is still working, killing X does not solve the problem, after some tries both monitor just go to sleep).

However, when I plug in the second monitor after bootup, it works fine. (standard ubuntu 12.04 kernel). After updating to the newest linux 3.4rc2 Kernel this problem is still present, however suspend and resume works fine with dualhead (didn't work with the old kernel) and the fan of the graphics card doesn't go wild anymore after resume. One of the monitors is attached directly over DVI-D the other is attached with an DVI-I to VGA adapter. Both of them are independently working fine. In the system settings they are both identified correctly with the correct resolution, however things like rotation is buggy and kind of crashes as well. (I have to change resolution AND rotation simultaniously in order to change the rotation otherwise the system crashes).

Is there some logfile I could post where these errors would be logged?

3d-Acceleration is working on both monitors when I plug in the second monitor after bootup.

`lspci` output:

```
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI R520 [Radeon X1800]
    01:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI R520 [Radeon X1800] (Secondary)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI R520 [Radeon X1800]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 0b12
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon

01:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI R520 [Radeon X1800] (Secondary)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 0b13
```

`lshw` output:

```
       *-display:0
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: R520 [Radeon X1800]
            vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
            resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ceee0000-ceeeffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ceec0000-ceedffff
       *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
            description: Display controller
            product: R520 [Radeon X1800] (Secondary)
            vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:ceef0000-ceefffff
```

EDIT 1:
By now I also compared the two Xorg.0.log files (coldplug vs hotplug) but I couldn't find suspicous behaviour. (only an error loading fglrx which was on both logs and is clear because I use the open source driver)

EDIT 2:
checked xrandr -d :0 everything seems fine to me

  `Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192

  DVI-0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm

   1920x1200      60.0*+

   1920x1080      60.0

   1600x1200      60.0

   1680x1050      60.0

   1280x1024      60.0

   1280x960       60.0

   1024x768       60.0

   800x600        60.3

   640x480        60.0

   720x400        70.1

S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DVI-1 connected 1280x1024+1920+176 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm

   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0

   1152x864       75.0

   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0

   832x624        74.6

   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2

   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0

   720x400        70.1`

I also checked dmesg but I was unable to find anything suspicious.

Could Someone name another logfile to look at, or should I file a bugreport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got it to work by implementing an xrandr script in the startup procedure as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution/74917#74917). My code in the script looks like that:

`#!/bin/sh

xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary --mode 1920x1200

xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 1920x37`

I would still be glad if someone were to point out in which module the bug resides so I can file a detailed bug report. Because it looks like xrandr should be ran before the loginwindow pops up or the window manager starts.