# Login screen resolution causes monitor to be "Out of Range"

Tags: xrandr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

Today I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS and I am experiencing some resolution problems. I fixed my desktop, but my welcome screen is "Out of Range" and then I press Ctrl-Alt- (-) (from the Numlock keypad) to make it bearable to see where do I have to type my password. After this my desktop run in the preferred resolution (1440x900).

What do I have to do to fix my welcome screen resolution?

I tried this but it didn't work:

- [Wrong Login Screen Resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution)

Comment: Hello, you can try [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution) out.

Comment: SOLVED! --> Solution from here: How can I make xrandr customization permanent? the second answer to this thread ("Modify /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf to add the following options:.....Cheers!")