# Apply Display Config to all users

Tags: 18.04, xorg

I had some trouble with the monitor setup and after some trial and error I could fix it by changing the refresh rate within `settings > devices > displays`. That works for the user that is logged in and each this very logs in again.

How can I make this change permanent and set as global default for all users?

Since ubuntu 18.04 does not use lightdm anymore, this is not a dublicate of answers for ubuntu below 18.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply display settings to all user accounts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639469/apply-display-settings-to-all-user-accounts)