# How do I apply display settings to login screen in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, display

Ubuntu's Display Settings seem to be user-specific and are not applied until after login. How can I make my display settings apply to the login screen as well?

(This is quite annoying cause it causes the login screen to pop up on whatever monitor Ubuntu defaults as the "main screen". In my case, this happens to be my 4K TV situated well away from my desk.)

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/642619/334280) does not work since Ubuntu changed display manager from LightDM to GDM in 16.04.

Comment: Each user can have their own settings, and they only take effect after login by design. Your alternative is to have a different set of configs for the DM itself as some DMs allow for this. GNOME has its own DM (GNOME Display Manager) and Ubuntu switched to it with 17.10 when they returned to using the GNOME Desktop (*it's the most efficient with GNOME*). Some *flavors* of Ubuntu use alternatives (`sddm` used by 3, `lightdm` ...) but modification of each is DM specific, and DM is changable (GDM just most efficient with GNOME)

Comment: Voting to close: This is a reported, active bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3867

Comment: Workaround is to use GDM config to define a primary monitor: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3867#note_1056590

Comment: @user535733 An issue being a bug is not a reason to close a question. Either a workaround, or "This is a known bug", or both, should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks I'll check out the workaround when I get home tonight and report if it worked