# Dual monitor screens are reversed only in login screen

Tags: nvidia, login, multiple-monitors, monitor

Today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer. I have dual monitor setup, and they work perfectly when I'm logged into the operating system. But every time I have to login in the login screen, the screens get reversed. And what I mean is that instead of moving the cursor on the main screen to the left to move on the secondary screen, I have to move it to the left side. After login it changes to normal.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Graphics: NVidia GTX275. Latest drivers installed.

Comment: Normally on dual monitors, the login follows the mouse, so should not matter. Probably easier to switch the hardware and re-congigure the desktop over re-congiure the login

Comment: well yeah it follows the cursor but after login it changes to normal, so the screens flash once, and the background is not showing correctly for 1-2 seconds. That's the reason I'm trying to find a fix about it.

Comment: I believe it is going to behave this way regardless. As I said, it is easier to swap the cables then fix the login screen config.

Comment: Okay speaking about cables, the one is an older display which can only be connected on VGA output and the main display is on DVI. They can not be swapped.

Comment: You would need to use an adapter. At any rate you can try this - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#LigthDM_displaying_in_wrong_monitor

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises because the login screen configuration file is located elsewhere, and your home folder holds your personalised configuration for use after login.

I had the same gripe with Zorin.

All you need to do is either copy or symlink from your personal config file to the default lightdm config file...

To copy... (ie make an orphan copy of your config)

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/lightdm/.config/
```

To symlink... (ie a LIVE link to your config, which is then used every time!)

```
sudo ln ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/lightdm/.config/
```

Both solutions are referenced in [THIS POST](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360886/personalize-monitor-position-before-login)

HTH :D

Edit: I am now using Mint 19. The monitors.xml file now appears to be in ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml