# Monitor setup during login is different to after login

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, login-screen, monitor

I have two monitors plugged into my machine. Monitor 1 connects via HDMI, and Monitor 2 connects via DVI. Physically, Monitor 1 is on the left of Monitor 2. In Screen Display Settings, Monitor 1 is set to be to the left of Monitor 2.

Now, when I boot into Ubuntu 14.04, at the login screen, the login box is shown on Monitor 2. Also, Monitor 1 is setup to be to the right of Monitor 2. This is the opposite to what I want.

But then after logging in, things switch round: Monitor 1 is the main screen with the desktop icons, and Monitor 1 is set up to be to the left of Monitor 2. This is how I want it.

So, the situation after logging in is as I want it, but at the login screen, things are the reverse. How can I change it so that both during and after login, my set up is as I want it?

Comment: Did you check the config in system settings>hardware>Displays?

Comment: Yes, in System Settings->Hardware->Screen Display, Monitor 1 is to the left of Monitor 2, as I want it.

Comment: you may want to look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/550128/dual-monitor-screens-are-reversed-only-in-login-screen
Did you try to swap the cables?

Comment: See @Fabby  's answer "and for the login screen".  Please mention if you (don't)  manage.