# How to configure login screen resolution in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: lightdm, display-resolution

i'm using ubuntu 15.10 64bit. I have a problem with the login screen. I can't see the login screen because login screen's resolution setting is big for my monitor. My gpu card can't read my monitor's max. resolution because my monitor has VGA input but my gpu card has dvi output so my monitor's max. resolution informations going to death on dvi-vga adapter. So i want change login screen's resolution, how to i can do it ? i bored the out of range error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I safely change grub2 screen resolution?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)

Comment: @CharlesGreen The login screen (greeter) is *not* the GRUB boot menu! You should revoke your close vote.

Comment: what i must do guys ?

Comment: The solution posted in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360886/personalize-monitor-position-before-login/363992#363992) worked when I tried in on a virtual machine

Comment: i dont understand it. can you just say what i must to do ? please...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong Login Screen Resolution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution)