# Make lightdm login on the correct monitor?

Tags: lightdm, displayport

Is there a way to get lightdm to display on the correct monitor? It defaults to my DVI monitor on the right, but I want it on the DP monitor on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is the answer: [Personalize monitor position before login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360886/personalize-monitor-position-before-login)

Really wish that was automated behind the scenes.