# Dual monitor setup not working on XFCE login screen

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, login-screen, multiple-monitors

I've had this problem before where the dual monitor setup would not be kept (i.e. I had my right screen as the main screen, but after restarting, the position of my right screen would be shifted to the left.), did a fresh reinstall and the problem got fixed (probably some other DE configs overriding each other since I had KDE, Gnome and Unity).

However, the problem now is that the dual monitor setup would be still broken on the login screen (my right screen would become the left one) and the screen config would only be fixed after I had logged in.

Comment: Do you know if you're using `lightdm` or some other display manager?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm definitely using lightdm, however there's no `lightdm.conf` file, only `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` and `users.conf` with a empty `lightdm.conf.d` folder.

Comment: what about http://askubuntu.com/questions/360886/personalize-monitor-position-before-login

Comment: @Zacharee1 Tried that, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: no effect at all?

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes, absolutely nothing happened.

Comment: @dll Did you have any luck with my answer posted below? Thanks

Comment: @jbrock Nope, all it did was put my system in low graphics mode. I belive that the newer versions of lightdm doesn't use `lightdm.conf` anymore. I also found out that it was a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1311399) with Gnome. Gonna try and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Install `arandr` by pasting the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt install arandr
```

Open arandr. Your screens are probably configured how you like. If so, go to Layout > Save As. Open the saved script and copy the entire `xrandr` command.

Create the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf if it is not created already. You can use:

```
sudo mousepad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Now paste the following. Replace my `xrandr` command below with your own.

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script=xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x72 --rotate normal --output DVI-0 --mode 1440x900 --pos 3360x82 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1440x0 --rotate normal
```

Reboot and your login screens should be correct.

Comment: This fixed it for me.