# Ubuntu 17.10 monitor position on login screen

Tags: 17.10, login-screen

So I've configured my desktop so that Monitor 1 is on the left, while Monitor 2 is on the right.

But after a reboot, the monitors switched position, so Monitor 1 is on the right, while Monitor 2 is on the left. (They reverted to my desktop configuration after login).

I have read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/360886), but that's for LightDM. There is no `/var/lib/lightdm` in 17.10

So, how do I change the login screen monitor configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your monitors.xml file is set up the way you want your monitors to be after you log in, try this and reboot.  Note that by default there is no existing monitors.xml file under /var/lib/gdm3/.config (at least it wasn't there for my setup.)

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config
```

Comment: I've also verified that this works on 18.04

Comment: I cannot get gdm3 to read the monitors.xml file at all under 18.04 and nor will it respond to a xrandr command in /etc/gdm3/Init/Default - so for me the only answer was to dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 to use lightdm - at least I can now actually access the logon screen on the second monitor (TV).

Comment: Did you make sure the /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml was changed back to root as the owner with privileges of 664 after you copied yours over?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this by uncommenting the `#WaylandEnable=false` setting under `[daemon]` and saving at the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` location on my triple monitor setup. found the resolution here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397584&p=13788383#post13788383