# Monitor position on login in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu

I'ive configured my 1st monitor to be on the right and and 2nd monitor to be on
the left.

It works as it should except on login screen. It is always on wrong position.

How can I change it?

Comment: How did you configu t wre the montors? Did you use monitor settings from the login screen? How that works is when you login to the lubuntu session it then sets the screen to to those settings. I am not quite sure on how to customize lightdm and multiple displays.  As such this sounds like a duplicate of. https://askubuntu.com/questions/360886/personalize-monitor-position-before-login

Comment: I've configured it via lubuntu screen display and nvidia x server settings. In nvidia x server settings saved settings to x configuration file. I have no .config/monitors.xml. so the workaround from your link doesnt help me.  https://askubuntu.com/a/862291/810719 only changes focus of the login screen but screens stay the same wrong swapped position.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
On login screen I've changed window manager to openbox and logged in. 
Next I've opened terminal and typed "sudo nvidia-settings", changed monitor positions and saved settings. Now login screen has desired monitor configuration.