# Xubuntu 14.04: Screen Resolution 1440x900, no xorg.conf or lightdm.conf

Tags: resolution, display-manager, display-resolution

So I'm quite confused now by the fact that I read a lot of different solutions for a Screen Resolution problem, but none of them apply to my case (I think).

So I'm running a Xubuntu 14.04 x64 and cannot get my LG Flatron W1934S suitable with the system.

cvt output:

```
linuxdev@linux-dev-pc:~$ cvt 1440 900
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

as for now the screen work perfectly by using the following lines

```
$: xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
$: xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
$: xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

And underneath the current situation:

```
linuxdev@linux-dev-pc:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1440x900       59.9  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1440x900_60.00   59.9* 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

LSHW display output:

```
*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:fe980000-fe9fffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe940000-fe97ffff
```

**Now is the big question; how do I create a permanent record for it?**

What I tried till now is to look into the 'xorg.conf', that does not exist anymore after upgrading. When I manually create the 'xorg.conf' the system craps out and will not boot anymore into the GUI. Through the terminal, I need to remove the 'xorg.conf' to get it booted again into the normal state with the low resolution.

Also the 'lightdm.conf' is quite a hassle to find or adjust so my options run very low at the moment. (The only lightdm.conf that I found is located at /etc/init, but with the output from the file I don't have a clue where or what to edit)

/etc/init/lightdm.conf output:

```
linuxdev@linux-dev-pc:~$ cat /etc/init/lightdm.conf
# LightDM - light Display Manager
#
# The display manager service manages the X servers running on the
# system, providing login and auto-login services
#
# based on gdm upstart script

description "LightDM Display Manager"
author      "Robert Ancell <robert.ancell@canonical.com>"

start on ((filesystem
           and runlevel [!06]
           and started dbus
           and plymouth-ready)
          or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)

stop on runlevel [016]

emits login-session-start
emits desktop-session-start
emits desktop-shutdown

script
    if [ -n "$UPSTART_EVENTS" ]
    then
        # Check kernel command-line for inhibitors, unless we are being called
        # manually
        for ARG in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
            if [ "$ARG" = "text" ]; then
        plymouth quit || : 
                stop
        exit 0
            fi
        done

    [ ! -f /etc/X11/default-display-manager -o "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/bin/lightdm" -o "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] || { stop; exit 0; }

    if [ "$RUNLEVEL" = S -o "$RUNLEVEL" = 1 ]
    then
        # Single-user mode
        plymouth quit || :
        exit 0
    fi
    fi

    exec lightdm
end script

post-start script
    sleep 5
    clear > /dev/tty7
end script

post-stop script
    clear > /dev/tty7
    sleep 1
    if [ "$UPSTART_STOP_EVENTS" = runlevel ]; then
        initctl emit desktop-shutdown
    fi
end script
```

**Thanks for the read and eventual reply!**

Comment: So, what's the actual question? What happens? Do you need to run these commands every time you reboot? Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/445957/85695) help?

Comment: Yes indeed, I always to run the commands after every reboot.

Comment: OK, did you read the Q&A I linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: `linuxdev@linux-dev-pc:~$ ls /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
50-greeter-wrapper.conf  50-guest-wrapper.conf  50-xserver-command.conf  60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` I have no 50-ubuntu.conf as mentioned in the specific post you pointed out.

Comment: Just create it if it's not there.

Comment: Nope, didn't work at all. How could it be this difficult? Adding the action to the Xorg.conf was much easier... Could it be a Ubuntu vs. Xubuntu thing?

Comment: Ah, it might very well be a Xubuntu vs Ubuntnu thing. Does Xubuntu use lightdm or does it have a different login manager? Did you try making a script of the `xrandr` commands and adding that to your xfce startup programs? That's not the most elegant of solutions but it should work.

Comment: Well I think that's the only thing I can do, I will stick with the 'startup' script. Thanks!

Comment: dupe of [How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent)

Answer (score 1):

Very good stuff.

I had some issues keeping my second monitor in the correct position. On boot the system would automatically try to mirror my screens even though I saved them in a specific position. I assume it was something to do with loading into a different resolution than last used (since it wasn't added yet through xrandr).

I was able to fix my issue with an additional step. After I had my desktop set up how I wanted (i.e. adding the new mode and initializing it) I installed "arandr" and saved my current desktop setup to a single line shell command. Then the final script made sure my desktop came up in the correct location every time. My full script now runs at autostart and works in my Kubuntu setup perfectly.

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output DP3 --off --output DP2 --off --output DP1 --off --output HDMI3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00 --pos 1920x104 --rotate normal
```

I hope this helps anyone in this situation.