# Black screen after deleting nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I decided to change nvidia-prime to bumblebee. I removed the nvidia-prime, installed bumblebee and restarted the computer. Loading freezes on plymouth. Then I booted into recovery mode and uninstall the driver nvidia-355 and bumblebee. Thereafter, at logon screen turns black. In the middle of the screen there is a cursor, which can not be moved. Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Look here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/699228/15-10-nvidia-graphics-issues/699239#699239