# Ubuntu 14.10 - Wrong greeter screen resolution

Tags: display, resolution, lightdm

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.10 set to a resolution of `1920 x 1080`, but on start up of the system, the resolution is incorrectly set to `3840 x 2160` (with no scaling) at the greeter screen. On subsequent accesses of the greeter screen by *locking the system*, the resolution is at the correctly set resolution of `1920 x 1080`, but by *logging out*, the resolution reverts to `3840 x 2160`.

I have noticed that there is another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution) addressing a similar issue but I'm not sure if the solutions apply to Ubuntu 14.10. Copying `~/.config/monitors.xml` to `/var/lib/lightdm/.config` appeared to resolve the problem but the screen displayed the incorrect resolution briefly, before "flashing" and displaying the correct resolution.