# Kubuntu 15.04 - Wrong log in screen resolution on laptop

Tags: kubuntu, display, resolution

I realise that there are similar questions on this problem for Ubuntu, including a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607028/ubuntu-14-10-wrong-greeter-screen-resolution) that I asked myself, but I have the same problem with Kubuntu 15.04.

My Kubuntu system is set to a resolution of `1920 x 1080` through Display Configuration settings. On system start-up (or after logging out and logging in again), the `1920 x 1080` resolution is not applied and the login screen resolution is incorrectly set to the native screen resolution of `3840 x 2160`, but *changes back to the correct setting* after logging in.

I was interested in why this seems to be occurring, and if there are any solutions that will apply the correct settings on system start-up and after log in. For reference, my laptop is a [Lenovo Y50 UHD](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/y-series/y50-uhd/).

Comment: I really would LOVE the reputation points, but I don't think it would be right for me to take credit for someone else's ideas, unless of course I had improved upon them.  I think this question has been asked and answered....http://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution

Comment: I referenced it in the [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/607028/ubuntu-14-10-wrong-greeter-screen-resolution) I asked before but I don't think they apply to Kubuntu (and there were also some other problems that I mentioned in that post). Does Kubuntu use LightDM as the display manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this on my laptop:

1. Create a new `xorg.conf` file and copy it to `/etc/X11`
2. Under `Section "Monitor"` add the following line

   ```
   Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
   ```
3. Under `Section "Screen"` in `SubSection "Display"` add the `Modes` entry below the `Depth` line as shown.

   ```
   Viewport   0 0
   Depth     24
   Modes "1920x1080"
   ```

These changes will make "1920x1080" the default resolution for login and session.

To generate the `xorg.conf` file you need to go to `tty1` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and after login stop the `X` server (`sudo service lightdm stop`) and issue `sudo X -configure`. Then copy the temporary `xorg.conf.new` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 15.04 doesn't have `lightm` for the login screen, instead the new `sddm`. It is still in the development phase actually. Look for issues [here](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found there were to patch this but without a real reason.

According to documentation of `sddm`:

```
_DisplayCommand_=
Path of script to execute when starting the display server. Default value is "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup".
```

The obvious solution is therefore to add the `xrandr` command to `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`. This can be easily retrieve with `ARandR`.