# How to autostart `xrandr` in Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Tags: xrandr, autostart, init, mate

I am happily using Ubuntu Mate 15.04 (Mate 1.8.2) and I need to run a `xrandr` script in every initialization to correct the resolution of my external monitor.

But it doesn't has a `/etc/mdm/Init/...`

In `gnome-fallback` I used `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` but, for obvious reasons, Mate doesn't use GDM.

Where is the correct place to insert my `xrandr` commands in Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: Put your xrandr command (with the full path to xrandr) in ~/bin . chmod a+x ~/bin/xrandr_script and call it at login http://www.howtogeek.com/103640/how-to-make-programs-start-automatically-in-linux-mint-12/

Comment: Is there a place I can put my script in order to make it execute globally (before someone logins).

Comment: Well, better to configure X properly then - http://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution

Comment: If you configure X properly, as in the link i gave you, it will work with everything that runs on X (login manager, desktop, etc). As you are running xrandr it should be trivial to configure X

Comment: Thanks! I will test but it seems to be the way to go.