# Login screen resolution to high but after login its ok

Tags: login-screen, display-resolution

i have bought a this new Zenbook UX305F from Asus, and instaled Ubuntu 14.4. After install every thing was to small on screen this means too high resolution 3200x1800, i then selected 1320x768 and its ok now. But, when i start the laptop the login screen resolution is still 3200x1800, and it does not look nice. Now, i dont know how exactly i should change this, i have tried some of the exaples on askubuntu.com but i endet up with low grafiks mode .....
To mention, i just use ubuntu becouse its free, for short im a newbee, but i know at least what terminal is.
So please help me with this small bug please.
PS: it uses Intel® HD Graphics 5300 (Broadwell GT2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong Login Screen Resolution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution)