# After unlocking my sleeping, multi-screen display, some of my windows have moved. Why?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 18.04, workspaces

Fresh install of 18.04.

GeForce GTX 1070 with three monitors.  Two via HDMI, one via DVI.

Using the nvidia driver (I think).  NVIDIA X Server Settings app is reporting NVIDIA Driver Version 396.24.

Settings-Privacy-Screen Lock:On

When I return to my screen-sleeping computer and type my password to unlock, some of the windows on some of the workspaces have moved.  I think it's only the workspace that appears immediately after the unlock, but, I have too many windows and too many workspaces to accurately know.

To me, it seems random which windows move, but, it's usually one or two, on only one workspace (I am usually utilizing multiple workspaces at a time).

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem in the past. This was caused by the fact that the screen would temporarily revert to a lower resolution (which caused windows and icons to move) during suspend, hibernation, screen locking and/or switching external monitors. Perhaps this is what's happening in your case as well. Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794074/login-screen-resolution) and see if that points you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, grub's available video modes top out at 1920x1080 on my system, whereas my desktop is running at 5760x1080.