# Wrong resolution of login screen

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, display-resolution, unity-greeter

I have a problem with login screen.

1) After boot-up the login screen appears with correct resolution (i.e. my default 3200x1800). However, after a fraction of second it changes to some ~1600x1200. After login everything is back to normal.

I know that this is "standard" problem with two displays. And that this should be solved (but it didn't work for me) by some (e.g., [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution)) `xrandr` script added to lightdm. However, I have just single screen (rarely I attach some external screen to give presentation).

2) When the system is back from suspension (is awaken) I don't have "normal" login screen but instead I see
[image: login screen]
This is happening only after suspension.

3) When I try to configure lightdm (`dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`) I have lighdm and lightDM
[image: lightdm]
The first one on the list (lightDM) is not working. What is the difference ?