# Login screen gets cursed

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, lts, amdgpu

[image: how it looks]

It gets cursed only on login. Everything else working fine.
I tried to reinstall the system, downgrade to 18.04 and reinstalling desktop environment.

Comment: It is possible that the resolution for the LightDM is not correct.  Possible solution:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Wayland problem. My graphics card doesn't support it, and screen got scrambled