# Screen resolution capability not correct with Nvidia GTX1060 with Nouveau and Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

My old display died and was replaced with a Philips 28" 288E2 model, capable of 3840x2160 resolution (aka 4K). A laptop has integrated Intel UHD Graphics (v2.0). The display is detected when plugged in via HDMI to the laptop and the full resolution is available and selected as the secondary display. This under Xubuntu 21.10 Everything works as expected, in other words.

A desktop machine is fitted with a Nvidia GTX1060 3GB card. Using exactly the same display and HDMI cable the highest resolution detected is 1920x1080. This is with the Nouveau driver and both 21.10 and, now, 22.04 LTS.

I have forced lightdm into 3840x2160 mode by following the recipe given in [Wrong Login Screen Resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution) so I have a graphics workaround for the time being. However, it seems to me that the Nouveau driver should be able to pick up the GPU's capability.

What I really want to do is to run CUDA on the desktop system. The Nvidia driver modules (I have tried several, including the currently recommended 510 version, on both 21.10 and 22.04LTS) are not loaded by the kernel at boot time. I have tried adding pci=realloc to /boot/grub/grub.cfg but that made no difference. Consequently I don't have a usable display and need to ssh in from another machine to roll back to the Nouveau solution.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to get the Nvidia driver working, and hence enable CUDA?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: *... are not loaded by the kernel at boot time* means you need either (1) disable Secure Boot in UEFI, the easiest way unless dual-booting with Windows 11, in which case you have to (2) use MOKutil to sign the Nvidia proprietary drivers. That's all.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. I was fairly sure that Secure Boot was disabled in UEFI and have just verified it to be the case.  Something else must be wrong.

Comment: What does `mokutil --sb-sate` says? If it confirms it as disabled then you may need to purge all Nvidia drivers (experiments often result in multiple version and consequently incompatibility - using Additional Driver avoids the problem thanks to running that routine whenever users try to change driver versions) and install again, preferably with Additional Drivers ONLY the recommended version.

Comment: After installing it, it says: EFI variables are not supported on this system

Comment: So that means you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode (must be used for old BIOS based PCs of a decade ago or older, and no one other). All bets are off.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like a re-install may be called for.  8-(

Answer (score -1):

I am now convinced that this is a hardware incompatibility arising from trying to connect the Nvidia 1060 to the Philips 288E2 over HDMI. The card doesn't have a DP output and the monitor doesn't have DVI-D so I am stuck with what I have - 4k display with the Nouveau driver.

A fresh install of Ubuntu with UEFI boot brought a lot of grief and no solution. Oh well.

My thanks to ChanganAuto for patient assistance.